# how can i post nested json objects to server in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

How can I post to the server? I need to post an JSON object using Retrofit 2. My JSON object is

```
    {
    "test_id":5,
    "user_id":null,
    "org_id":2,
    "schedule_id":15,
    "group_id":null,
    "next_section_id":"",
    "current_section":
    {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make give json into one pojo class and pass into api calling like..

```
    @POST("path")
Call<ResponseData> passJsonData(@Body JsonData jsonData); // here pass your request data pojo class object..
```

when calling that time only create object and pass all data into object and pass into api call method.

like ..

```
        JsonData data=new JsonData();
    data.setId("1");
    data.setName("Abcd");
    Call<ResponseData> responseCall =apiInterface.passJsonData(data);
```

Comment: i update my answer.

Comment: how can i post multiple object

Comment: store all boject into array then pass array

Comment: thank i will tried but it not worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51113045/i-tried-to-post-jsonobject-in-retrofit

Answer (score 1):

Below are some ways to achieve this:

1.

```
@POST("/path")
void sendPost(@Body EventPayload body, Callback<Response> onSuccess);
```

here EventPayload is the POJO representation of your request

2.

```
@POST("/path")
void sendPost(@Body String body, Callback<Response> onSuccess);
```

here body is the serialized JSON in the string form